# How do I expand this product

Tags: probability, products

How do I expand the following product:

\begin{equation}
\prod_{j=i+1}^n (1-\frac{1}{j})
\end{equation}

Wolfram Alpha tells me the answer is $i/n$, which is the answer I was looking for, but I have no idea how to derive this by hand.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The product expands as
$$\frac i{\color{red}{i+1}}\cdot\frac{\color{red}{i+1}}{i+2}\cdots\frac{n-2}{\color{blue}{n-1}}\frac{\color{blue}{n-1}}n$$
which telescopes down to $\frac in$ (numerator and denominator of adjacent fractions cancel).